# laravelでパスワード再発行画面が表示されないエラーに関して質問があります。

Tags: laravel

こちらのlaravelのチュートリアルで練習をしているのですが質問があります。
https://www.hypertextcandy.com/laravel-tutorial-authentication-part-2

開発環境　AWScloud9

【実現したいこと】
ログイン画面にパスワード変更こちらにアクセスするとパスワード再発行ページに
遷移してメールアドレスを入力して「再発行リンクを送る」ボタンをクリックするとmailtrapのデモinboxにメールを送りたいです。
https://i.gyazo.com/f9e43eeadccb39f41f8a1ebe6988e554.png

【起こったエラー】
パスワードの変更はこちらからのボタンを押すと
[image: Image from Gyazo]

こちらのようなエラーが表示されます。
【試してみた事】
tinkerを起動してメール文がmailtrapに届いているか試したのですがこちらは問題なく送れました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596795/view-auth-emails-password-not-found
こちらで試して調べてやってみたのですが、以前エラーが表示されまます。
どなたかわかるかたお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

実際にやったことはもう少し具体的に書いてください。(試してみたこと、以前にそこまでの経緯を)
またエラー内容はテキストで書き起こしてくださいね、今回だと **`View [auth.passwords.email] not found`** ですね。

さて、今回の内容はおそらく **エラーをよく読んでください** で片付けられてしまう内容です。[参照先](https://www.hypertextcandy.com/laravel-tutorial-authentication-part-2#%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)に

> **パスワード再設定メール送信ページ**
> `resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php` を以下の内容で作成してください。

とあるのですが、これを飛ばしていたりあるいは作成するファイル名を誤っていたりしないでしょうか、確認してみてください。

---

実際に何が問題なのかを誤解されているようなきもするのですが、今回の問題は「メールが送れない」ではなくて「メール送信画面が表示できない」です(タイトル見る限りその認識のようなきもしますが)。まずはエラーメッセージを読んでもらえれば分かるかと。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もう少し具体的に書いたほうがよかったのともう一度エラーメッセージをよく確認してみます。ご指摘のとおりファイル名が間違っていないかどうかも確認してみます。

Comment: 確認したところご指摘の通りemail.blade.phpのファイル名が間違っていました。直したところきちんと表示されました。ありがとうございました。